# Website's locales correctly crawled but badly displayed

Tags: web, internationalization, translation, facebook-opengraph, facebook-wall

I have a multi-language website which is correctly crawled by Facebook, but badly displayed on Facebook walls.

The site exists in two languages, therefore I have set up two different sets of og properties, one for each language:

English:

```
<meta property="og:title" content="Perehana, the best way to find perfect gifts!"/>
<meta property="og:type" content="website"/>
<meta property="og:url" content="http://www.perehana.com"/>
<meta property="og:image" content="http://www.perehana.com/img/large-icon.jpg"/>
<meta property="og:site_name" content="Perehana"/>
<meta property="og:description" content="No gift ideas for Christmas, birthdays, weddings, births or any other event? Perehana allows you to enter gift ideas and to reserve your family and friends' ideas before buying them."/>
<meta property="og:locale" content="en_GB"/>
<meta property="fb:app_id" content="242045389185230"/>
<meta property="og:locale:alternate" content="fr_FR"/>
```

French:

```
<meta property="og:title" content="Perehana, le meilleur moyen de faire plaisir à coup sûr !"/>
<meta property="og:type" content="website"/>
<meta property="og:url" content="http://www.perehana.com"/>
<meta property="og:image" content="http://www.perehana.com/img/large-icon.jpg"/>
<meta property="og:site_name" content="Perehana"/>
<meta property="og:description" content="En manque d'idées de cadeaux à l'approche de Noël, des anniversaires, des mariages ou des naissances ? Perehana est un site qui vous permet de saisir des idées-cadeaux et de réserver celles de votre famille et de vos amis. Vous pouvez ensuite aller les acheter sans qu'ils le sachent."/>
<meta property="og:locale" content="fr_FR"/>
<meta property="fb:app_id" content="242045389185230"/>
<meta property="og:locale:alternate" content="en_GB"/>
```

As you can see, the locales and alternates are correctly set.
When I check in the Facebook debugger what has been crawled, everything looks fine: [http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.perehana.com&locale=fr_FR](http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http://www.perehana.com&locale=fr_FR)

The problem occurs when I want to post the URL (http://www.perehana.com) on my wall, the title and description that Facebook automatically fetches for the site are in English, even if my user account is in French... :-(

I still have lots of work to do on the site so I am getting quite desperate, this problem has taken me far too much time!

Thanks to anyone who can help!

Comment: I like the detail of your question.  +1,  I hope someone from Facebook could provide some insight on this issue.

Comment: It's been 4 days and no response from Facebook engineers or devs?!  I hope one of them step up to the plate and answer your question soon.

Comment: No, still no answer. :-( I also hope someone will be able to help soon!

Comment: I have opened a bug in the Facebook assistance section: http://developers.facebook.com/bugs/234215290010093

Answer (score 1):

When communicating from your Facebook fan page, you can select who gets to see which announcement in which language (based on their Facebook language and geographic location), totally independent of your own account & language settings. Maybe this is the issue, that you didn't set your communication to be language-specific?

Comment: Thanks for the information, I didn't know about it. Unfortunately, I get this error on my own wall: I'd like the details to be in the correct language if users share it on their wall.